# TestNG running all dependent tests for all input dataproviders

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

i have a test suite like below

```
@Test(dataProvider = "param1")
public void test1(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult) {
    System.out.println(inputNumber + " " + expectedResult);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, Boolean.TRUE);
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
public void test2() {
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
}


@DataProvider(name = "param1")
private static Object[][] jobRequests() {
    return new Object[][]{{2, true}, {6, true}, {19, true}, {22, true}, {23, true}};
}
```

I want to run the test2 for all the params that were passed to test1
in essence, i want parameterised test suites/ class level parameters

Comment: Your `test2` method does not accept parameters. Or that's a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Then you will need to write it as such, essentially you will need to pass the parameters to your Test2 as well.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "param1")
public void test1(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult) {
    System.out.println(inputNumber + " " + expectedResult);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, Boolean.TRUE);
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1", dataProvider = "param1")
public void test2() {
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: tried that, doesnt really help .the order or execution would be test1 for all params and then test2. i want it to be test1+ test2 for all params

Comment: basically parameterised test suite

Comment: You will need to specify the SUIT in testng.xml then, if you wanted to run a group of tests in parallel using the same input @JavageekGod, is this your question on how to?

Comment: yes precisely. can this be done?